# Is there any way to pass @Autowired variable to some other class in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

In my Spring Boot application, I have class A. In that class, I have declared my DAO layer variable with @Autowired annotation. I have a separate Java library which contains class B (which has a method that accepts generic parameters). I want to send the @Autowired variable from class A as a parameter to the method of class B and perform some operation with that variable in class B's method.

Is there any way to achieve this? Will the second class be aware of the context?

Comment: Yes you can do it. but what is the purpose of doing so.can you help me with a use case.

Comment: Spring bean is just another java object assembled based on your configurations and provided to you by the Spring container  . what happens when you pass this object to the library method ?

Comment: It is showing up as null.

Comment: @Dinu trying to build a simple app where an external library can be used.

Comment: In Spring when the class is invoked the autowired variables are initialized first so that you can pass that value to other methods and classes. But make sure the class where yopu are calling the autowired is either a component or service

Comment: "But make sure the class where yopu are calling the autowired is either a component or service " - does this mean that the other class has to be a spring bean?

Comment: Not needed to be a spring bean it can be simple pojo also

Comment: The variable is returning "null".

Comment: @awesomemypro that's because your code has a bug. But you didn't post your code, so we can't find it and explain it.

Comment: Note that (1) using constructor injection eliminates many of these bugs and (2) you can use an `@Bean` method to provide autowired dependencies to third-party libraries.

Comment: I cannot use the @Bean since the library does not need Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the second class be aware of the context?

I assume, by second class you meant class B. ClassB doesnt need to be aware of the context. All it care is, it needs a non-null Object of DAO layer as method argument.

So, the question is, at what point are you trying to invoke the method in class B. If you are invoking it before spring completes it's part, then all you will get is `null`. Try calling the ClassB.method() from `@PostConstruct` annotated method and see whether you are still getting `null` reference for DAO member variable. If that's the case look at your spring bean instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it, but it is not a good practice. If you want to create a separate library then make it simple. You are increasing the dependency.

It is always recommended to follow loos coupling principle while building application.

Comment: How is it not following the loose coupling principle? Can you please explain it a bit more?