# Best way to initialize a variable and use it in 2 service classes in java , as thread safe

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hardcode

This is first class:

```
@Service
public class ServiceA{

@Autowired
ServiceB serviceB;

String neededString;

public void methodSome(){
//uses neededString
}

}
```

This is second

```
@Service
public class ServiceB{

String neededString;

public void methodSome(){
//uses neededString
}
}
```

and i need to get the variable from another service:

```
neededString = thirdServiceToReturn();
```

Both classes need that **neededString** variable to do their own methods. I can get from 3. service in the method seperately or i can get with **PostConstruct** for each class.

But i want to get from a common place for both classes. Maybe from 2. class . I can try **static** but it wont be thread safe i guess.

The variable wont change for months maybe. It takes some values and returns from database. After some deploy, it can change so, it should get new one at some point.

I use `Spring Boot` also. What do you suggest?

Maybe a `Constant` class with `@Bean` and do the initializing there and then `Autowired` to second class? Like that:
[Is there any way to pass @Autowired variable to some other class in a Spring Boot application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59559302/is-there-any-way-to-pass-autowired-variable-to-some-other-class-in-a-spring-boo)

The variable will change in future. It is reading from database, which is derived with @cached so it will read from cache until the application is restarted or is deployed. Variable needs to be parametric, not hardcoded.

`Static variable` is not thread safe. I want to reach the solution. Thread safe.

Comment: I don't understand the reason it needs to be threadsafe. All classes and instances are to share the same value. Also the value that is visible to all threads should change at the same time.

Comment: @JohnWilliams yes, should change at same time. So, it needs to be thread safe? Can i use static?

Comment: Yes, use a static. neededString does **not** need to be thread safe, it needs to be the opposite.

Comment: @JohnWilliams static string and initialize with postconstruct?

Comment: Yes, if it needs initialisation logic.

Comment: @JohnWilliams methodSome() needs to use that variable. Both class needs that variable so at first, it needs to be initialized at somewhere. Maybe at another bean or postconstruct are the options i think.

Answer (score 1):

This is first class:

```
@Service
public class ServiceA{

@Autowired
ServiceB serviceB;

public static String neededString;

@PostConstruct
public void setupNeededString() {
    neededString = “”;
}

public void methodSome(){
//uses neededString
}

}
```

This is second

```
@Service
public class ServiceB{



public void methodSome(){
//uses ServiceA.neededString
}
}
```